# How are 3-state cellular automata rules generated?

Tags: c, algorithm, cellular-automata

Let's limit the neighborhood to n=1 (which means we always need 3 cells to evaluate the next-gen cell).

[image: For]

Here's an example of a 2 state rule. Note that the upper row of the rules are generated in a particular order, whereas the lower row is the bit representation of the number 30.

I cannot find a single visualization of the equivalent for a 3 state CA. Following the logic of 2 state CA, it should contain 27 possible outcomes, but I have no clue in which order they should be generated. The lower row should be 30 in ternary (with leading zeroes to occupy a total of 27 positions).

Is there a general algorithm for generating these permutations in the conventional order of CAs (regardless of the number of states)?

Thank you very much in advance and sorry if the question is stupid. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are using is called Wolfram's code (from Stephen Wolfram) that is used for elementary CAs.
If you use more states or bigger neighborhoods then it is sufficient to extend it naturally.

Your question is not stupid.

For three states, this will give you ternary numbers. First write all the three digits number in ternary (descending order):

```
222, 221, 220, 212, 211, 210, 202, 201, 200, 122, 121, 120, 112, 111, 110, 102, 101, 100, 022, 021, 020, 012, 011, 010, 002, 001, 000
```

There are 27 of them 3^3, and 222_3 = 26, 221_3 = 25, 001_3 = 1, 000_3 = 0

Now decompose 30 onto base 3 27-digits number: 30 = 1*3^3+ 1*3^1, so there is only two digits equals to 1, the fourth and the second (from the right), here is rule 30 for radius-1 3-states CA:

```
000000000000000000000001010
```

This CA has a very different behavior than rule 30 radius-1 2-states CA.

Here is rule 33 for radius-1 3-states (33 = 1*3^3 + 2*3^1):

```
000000000000000000000001020
```

So for n,r, enumerate in descending order all 2r+1 digits numbers in base n and associate for each of them a value in [0,n[.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! This was very helpful!